# Ant Design Pro and @svgr/webpack

Tags: webpack, antd, ant-design-pro

can someone help me to figure out how to configure ant design pro to use svg as components using @svgr/webpack please?

What i done is:

in the plugin.config.js, inside the webpackPlugin function, i've added the following code:

```
const svgToComponentRule = config.module.rule('svg')
svgToComponentRule
    .test(/\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/)
    .include
        .add(path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/assets/icons-svg'))
        .end()
svgToComponentRule
        .use('babel-loader')
            .loader('babel-loader')
        .end()
        .use('@svgr/webpack')
            .loader('@svgr/webpack')
                .options({
                    babel: false,
                    icon: true,               
                })
                .end()
```

This does not work with the following error:

[image]

What is the problem?

Thanks to all for the help.

PS: @svgr/webpack is installed as dev dependecy module.